# NPM Package works when using local files but not when installing from remote package manager

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, npm-install, swiper.js

I have been scratching my head lately trying to create a custom React library.
More specifically, I have managed to create the library but I haven't been able to make it work when installing it from my gitlab package manager.

If I download the package to a local folder and then I run

```
npm i ./package-name
```

everything works fine.
However if I run

```
npm i @scope/package-name
```

I get the following error:

```
 Must use import to load ES Module: <root-path>\example-app\node_modules\swiper\swiper.esm.js
```

I honestly have no clue why the local installation works while the remote one doesn't.
Here is the package.json of the library:

```
{
  "name": "@scope/package-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "some components",
  "main": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc -p tsconfig-cjs.json",
    "create-package": "npm run clean && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "swiper": "^7.3.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "swiper": "^7.3.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what's the reason behind this?

Comment: can you provide link of the package on npm?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t because it’s a private package. But I could try to recreate a public sample